# Password Update in SL

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to update a password/Username of OS using Java API in Softlayer. 
But after executing API, Password is not modified. Here is the code i've tested.
Please comment me if you find any doubts. Thanks

```
import com.softlayer.api.ApiClient;
import com.softlayer.api.RestApiClient;
import com.softlayer.api.service.Hardware;
import com.softlayer.api.service.hardware.Server;
import com.softlayer.api.service.software.Component;
import com.softlayer.api.service.software.Description;
import com.softlayer.api.service.virtual.Guest;


        public void deviceSoftcomp_BM_reName() throws Exception {

        Server.Service bmService = Server.service(client, 8045737l);

        bmService.withMask().softwareComponents().passwords().username().password();
        bmService.withMask().softwareComponents().softwareDescription().name();

        Hardware hd = bmService.getObject();

        List<Component> compList =  hd.getSoftwareComponents();

        for (Component comp : compList) {
            Description desc = comp.getSoftwareDescription();
            System.out.println(" software name : " + desc.getName());
            Long softId = comp.getId();
            System.out.println(" software id : " + softId);


            List<com.softlayer.api.service.software.component.Password> passList = comp.getPasswords();

            for (com.softlayer.api.service.software.component.Password password : passList) {

                System.out.println(" Username : " + password.getUsername());
                System.out.println(" Password : " + password.getPassword());

                if(softId == 9824519){
                    System.out.println("--- Rename OS name " );
                    password.setUsername("newUser");
                    password.setPassword("xfdgasdf123");
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following:   [SoftLayer_Software_Component_Password::editObject](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Software_Component_Password/editObject)

Below is a REST example:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Software_Component_Password/[comp_pass_id]/editObject

Method: POST

Json Payload:
{
  "parameters": [
    {
      "password": "myPassEdited",
      "username": "myUserEdited"
    }
  ]
}
```

Also, to get passwords of server software components, please see:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Hardware/[server_id]/getSoftwareComponents?objectMask=mask[passwords]

Method: GET
```

Comment: As your example, I've created "editObject" to update it with password template and It works fine. Let me post what I have done as a reference in java for others. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is java sample code to update software in device.

```
     com.softlayer.api.service.software.component.Password passtemplate =
     new com.softlayer.api.service.software.component.Password();
     passtemplate.setUsername("newUserName");
     passtemplate.setPassword("123456abcDF");

    com.softlayer.api.service.software.component.Password.Service passService = com.softlayer.api.service.software.component.Password
            .service(client, 10000000l); // Client and password ID
    passService.editObject(passtemplate);
```