# Softlayer API: how to update/remove machine password

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am able to get VS OS password via SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest but now face the problem of updating the OS pass. How to update (preferable delete, or set blank) this.

Also not sure what the Software_Component_Password is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question about password update was answered here [Password Update in SL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36841283/password-update-in-sl)

In your case, for virtual guest you should be able to get all passwords of VSI with the following GET REST call

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/[server_id]/getSoftwareComponents?objectMask=mask[passwords,softwareLicense]
```

Change **[username]**, **[apikey]**, **[server_id]** with your own data.

You need to select a password id and use the following POST request in order to update it.

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Software_Component_Password/[password_id]/editObject


Body in JSON:
{
  "parameters": [
    {
      "password": "myPassEdited",
      "username": "myUserEdited"
    }
  ]
}
```

Try by sending an empty password, just set "" in password parameter.

With [Software_Component_Password](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Software_Component_Password) service you can [create](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Software_Component_Password/createObject), [edit](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Software_Component_Password/editObject), [delete](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Software_Component_Password/deleteObject) one or a list of passwords, I recommend you review information about this service.

Comment: Thanks for example, Reading official documentation was really not too helpful as I would never imagine how to transform classes and data types into this JSON.  I suggest you to create a REST api section on Bluemix/SL knowledgebase.

Comment: You can find some examples on different languages here https://softlayer.github.io/ including REST calls.