# Softlayer api passes username and password place order virtual server

Tags: python, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

1. I have used the softlayer Python API.
2. How to pass the username and password when we place in a virtual server?
3. I have no idea, how to pass the username and the password.

Here is my code:

```
import SoftLayer
client = SoftLayer.Client(username='XXXXXX',api_key='xxxxxx')


      vmorderparmers = {
         'hostname':'testhost',
         'domain': 'exampledomain.com',
        'datacenter': 'sjc01',
        'startCpus':1,
        'maxMemory': 1024,
        'localDiskFlag': True,
        'hourlyBillingFlag': True,
        'operatingSystemReferenceCode':'CENTOS_6_64',
        "blockDevices": [
            {
                "device": "0",
                "diskImage": {
                    "capacity": 100
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not get you question but I think your asking how to set the password and username to a virtual machine, the answer is that you cannot se those values at order time those values are set after the order has been done and the machine is already provisioned.

Also keep in mind that id you change the password using the API it only updates the password in the softlayer's database and not in the machine you need to update the password manually in the machine for that.

here an example about how to change it suing REST

[Password Update in SL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36841283/password-update-in-sl)

using pyrhon would be something like this

```
password = {
      "password": "myPassEdited",
      "username": "myUserEdited"
    }

client["SoftLayer_Software_Component_Password"].editObject(password, id=componentPasswprdId)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use metadata and provisioning scripts.
For example, the new username and password should be set in the metadata at the order, then you can retrieve metadata automatically after provisioning using the provisioning script.
In the provisioning script, you don't have to write down your SL API credentials.
In this way, you don't have to expose your new credentials and can apply to the new ordered server.